# Editing a knowledge article in apex

Tags: apex, unit-test, knowledge, articles

I'm trying to simulate an edit on a Knowledge Article for a unit test. I'd like to edit a field such that a new KnowledgeArticleVersionHistory record is created where the EventType == 'KavRevised,' as you'd get if you actually edited a field (like Cause or Resolution) on an article.

My guess is that something should go between the KbManagement.PublishingService.editOnlineArticle() and the publishOnlineArticle() but I'm not sure exactly what to get the desired behavior.

Here's my code.

```
How_To__kav kav1 = new How_To__kav(Title = 'Title 1a', Language = 'en_US', UrlName = 'url1', ValidationStatus = 'Not Validated'); // Create the KAV.
insert kav1; // Insert the KAV, creating an associated KA. 
List<How_To__kav> kavs1 = [SELECT KnowledgeArticleId FROM How_To__kav WHERE Id = :kav1.Id]; // Grab the KnowledgeArticleId.
KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(kavs1[0].KnowledgeArticleId, true); // Publish.
KbManagement.PublishingService.editOnlineArticle(kavs1[0].KnowledgeArticleId, true); // Edit.
KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(kavs1[0].KnowledgeArticleId, true); // Publish again.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you updating any fields during update?  What the actual issues you are facing?

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to update a field so that the KnowledgeArticleVersionHistory record is created. The issue is that I'm not really sure how to maneuver the bookkeeping framework to simulate this behavior via apex. Something like kav1.Title = '_____' doesn't work because you can't edit kavs and to the best of my knowledge there's not a field like 'Cause' on the KnowledgeArticle itself that you can edit.